# How to change character in textarea value?

Tags: javascript, input, replace, textarea

So, say I have a textarea.

```
 <textarea id="area">Test text</textarea>
```

How can I search for a specific string (For example, "text") and remove it?

I tried this, but to no avail.

```
  document.getElementById("area").replace('text', '');
```

Any and all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Modify the elements `.value` property, as it stands you are operating on the element object itself.

```
var el = document.getElementById("area");
el.value = el.value.replace('text', '');
```

Comment: Hi- not sure if this is necessary, but do you need a script to "reintroduce" the value? For example: document.getElementById("area").value = el.value;

Comment: No it works as-is. `el` is the textarea, you can read/write to it however you see fit.

Comment: Ah. I used another answer and got:  var area =  document.getElementById("area").value;
var newarea = area.replace('b', '');
document.getElementById("area").value = newarea;

Comment: In this case, I needed the last line. In your example, it's not necessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `.value` instead. However, you're looking to do a `replace` as well.

```js
let textarea = document.getElementById("area");
let currentString = textarea.value;
textarea.value = currentString.replace(/Test/, "Replaced");
```

```html
<textarea id="area">Test text</textarea>
```

Answer (score -3):

you can use this

```
function myFunction() {
var str = $("#area").text;
var n = str.search("blablabla");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
```

}

it's explained this link : [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp)

Comment: First, w3schools is traditionally a poor suggestion. Usually it's very out of date. Second, you're suggesting a very poor method versus what they're looking for. Manipulating the innerHTML for a simple string replacement should never be the answer.

Comment: `$"#area".text;` what on earth

Comment: you right w3schools out of date but it have pretty simple and well described examples. This features good for newbies like me like him. if u suggest better than w3 im listening you

Comment: You're suggesting jsref and jquery. Why on earth would you use that for what he wants when a simple `string.replace` works a thousand times better, and without all the additional overhead jquery requires?

Comment: mdn. the official jq docs. any blog, any one of the plethora of available books, videos, all better than w3schools. even SO Docs.

Comment: `textContent` is a much better option than `innerHTML`, since it doesn't parse as HTML.